# Send Keys on File Upload dialog throws org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException, message: 'Unable to determine type from: H. Last 1 characters read:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I am finding hard time in handling file upload using selenium on my Linux machine. This is my browse web element

Below is the code

```
final LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
        final File localFile = detector.getLocalFile(filePath);
        if (element instanceof RemoteWebElement) {
            ((RemoteWebElement) element).setFileDetector(detector);
        }
        final String absolutePath = localFile.getAbsolutePath();
        element.sendKeys(absolutePath)
```

I am facing the error as org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException, message: 'Unable to determine type from: H. Last 1 characters read: HBuild info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown',time: 'unknown'

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: <span data-class="a-button-inner"><input type="file" data-class="a-button-input" autocomplete="off" id="fileToUpload"><span class="a-letter-space"></span></span> pasting input tag element

Comment: Are you using `server-standalone-version.jar.`?

Comment: Web driver runs in sand boxed environment , which performs filesystem level isolation, hence i am not sure how can i copy the file of my local file system to the sandboxed environment and then upload ?

Comment: You can keep the files in project directory (eg. resources) folder.